# Why does my CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation doesn't work on iOS 7?

Tags: objective-c

On iOS 8 this code above works properly, but not on iOS 7, anybody knows how to fix it?

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    // headerFixed is an UIView inside of a headerView, i wanna it to be fixed on Y:0
    headerFixed.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, MIN(scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0)); 
}
```

on iOS 8: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-428J20xbzM&feature=youtu.be

on iOS 7 (BUG):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd_jh0zs1f0&feature=youtu.be

Comment: What happens when you run this on 7?

Comment: it scrolls with a half speed of the tableView, and don't stop at the y0

Comment: Looks like my solution below is working, would you mind to accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you build your project with iOS 8 SDK, then on iOS 7 you'll have to manually convert points to pixels on retina devices;

Consider writing something like this:

```
CGFloat dY = MIN(scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0);
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue < 8) {
   dY *= [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
}
headerFixed.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, dY);
```

There's a chance though that turning auto layout off will be enough to fix your problem.

Comment: You save my day! Thanks.